# Flask-PyMongo: how come "self._Collection__database"?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

In Flask-PyMongo, they use `self._Collection__database` to represent the database object that this Collection object belongs to:

```
class Collection(collection.Collection):
    """Custom sub-class of :class:`pymongo.collection.Collection` which
    adds Flask-specific helper methods.
    """

    def __getattr__(self, name):
    attr = super(Collection, self).__getattr__(name)
    if isinstance(attr, collection.Collection):
        db = self._Collection__database
        return Collection(db, attr.name)
    return attr
```

Why is `self._Collection__database` not `self.__database`?

```
test <a>and <i>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask-PyMongo is not arbitrarily choosing that name.
The name is the result of [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to
>   avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there
>   is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. Any
>   identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at
>   most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

In [the parent-class definition](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/collection.py#L100), the attribute is defined as `self.__database` and Python "mangles" the name (to `self._ClassName__attributename`) so that any subclasses do not overwrite with their own assignment to their own `self.__database` attribute.